# Significant text aggregation empty buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a significant text query, and I'm having issues with some integration testing where it always returns an empty array for a test case of 3 documents, with a shared term in a text field:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "filter":[
            {
               "exists":{
                  "field":"title"
               }
            },
            {
               "term":{
                  "type":"ITEM"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggregations":{
      "search-text":{
         "sampler":{
            "shard_size":100
         },
         "aggregations":{
            "keywords":{
               "significant_text":{
                  "field":"title",
                  "min_doc_count":1
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The index has 3 test documents in it, and they're returned by the query, they have a title field, it's a `text` field, but the buckets are empty, even though it reports `"doc_count":3` on the aggregation as a whole:

```
{
   "took":30,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{ ... },
   "hits":{
      "total":{
         "value":3,
         "relation":"eq"
      },
      "max_score":0,
      "hits":[
         {
            ...
            "_source":{
               "title":"Item1",
               "type":"ITEM"
            }
         },
         {
            ...
            "_source":{
               "title":"Item2",
               "type":"ITEM"
            }
         },
         {
            ...
            "_source":{
               "title":"Item 4",
               "type":"ITEM"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations":{
      "search-text":{
         "doc_count":3,
         "keywords":{
            "doc_count":3,
            "bg_count":3,
            "buckets":[]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Anyone know why it's not actually picking up the term "Item"?

Comment: I am having a similar issue did you find a solution?

Comment: Gosh, so long ago now... I *think* it was simply because there was not enough entries in my test data. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significanttext-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3 I'll try have a look at the code tomorrow.